# To get the particular id into the model in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I make one table booking project in php in this page i show all the tables details from the database.after i click on Success button there is one modal open and in that model i have create one field in that field i want to get the particular table id. For example:if i click on No 12 table than into a model i want get the 12 nub table id how to do it.Here i upload one image

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include('dbconnect.php');
        $sessionid=$_SESSION['login_user'];
        $userid=$_SESSION['worker'];
    /*  echo $userid;
    echo $sessionid; 
 */
    include('include/headeru.php');
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
         $bdate=$_POST['bdate'];
         $btime=$_POST['btime'];
         $checkdata=mysql_query(" SELECT restotable.t_id, restotable.t_name, 
                    restotable.t_capacity, restotable.t_type, restobooking.b_id ,
                    restobooking.first_name, restobooking.b_status 
                    FROM restotable 
                    LEFT JOIN restobooking ON restotable.t_id=restobooking.t_id AND
                    restobooking.b_date = '$bdate' AND restobooking.b_time='$btime'");  
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="asset/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<style type="text/css">
.custom-date-style {
    background-color: red !important;
}
.input{ 
}
.input-wide{
    width: 500px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-inline" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="date">Date:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datetimepicker2" placeholder="<?php
        echo date("Y/m/d")?>" value="<?php echo $bdate?>" name="bdate">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="time">Time:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datetimepicker1" placeholder="time" value="<?php echo $btime?>" name="btime">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">

    <div class="row">
      <?php
      $tableid= array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($checkdata) ) {
    ?>
      <div class="col-md-3" style="color:red">
        <div class="well" >
            <?php if($row["b_status"]==NULL){ ?>

            <div class="text-info"><i class="fa fa-weixin fa-lg"></i> <?php echo $row["t_id"]?></div>
            <h4 class="text-info" ><span class="label label-info pull-right">AVAILABLE</span><?php echo $row["t_name"]; ?></h4>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="test()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bookingmodel">Success</button>                     
            <?php } else {?>
                        <div><i class="fa fa-weixin fa-lg"></i> <?php echo $row["t_capacity"]?></div>
            <h4 class="text-danger" ><span class="label label-danger pull-right">BOOKED</span><?php echo $row["t_name"]; ?></h4>
          <?php }  ?>   
       </div>
      </div>
      <?php }   ?>
    </div><!--/row-->    
  </div><!--/col-12-->
</div>
<!--model-->
<div class="modal fade" id="bookingmodel" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">BOOKING TABLE</h4>
        </div>
         <div class="modal-body">

                <form id="bookingtable" role="form" action="insert.php" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="tablename">First Name</label>

                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bfirstname" name="bfirstname" placeholder="<?php echo $userid; ?>" />

                      <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="tablename">Last Name</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="blastname" name="blastname" placeholder="Last Name"/>
                      <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="tablename">Mobile No</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bmobileno" name="bmobileno" placeholder="Mobile No"/>
                      <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="tablecapacity">Check IN</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bcheckin" name="bcheckin" placeholder=" <?php echo $btime ?>"/>
                      <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>
                  </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="tablecapacity">Table Id</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bcheckin" name="bcheckin" value="<?php echo $row["t_id"]?>"/>
                      <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="tablecapacity">Check OUT</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bcheckout" name="bcheckout" placeholder="Check OUT"/>
                      <span class="help-block" id="error"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                        <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                                    Close
                        </button>-->
                        <button type="submit" name="bookingtable" id="bookingtable" class="btn btn-primary">Edit </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
              </div>
       </div>

    </div>
  </div>

<!--End model-->


</div> 


</body>
<script src="asset/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="asset/register.js"></script>

<script src="asset/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="asset/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
<script>

function test(){
             $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'check.php',
            success: function(d) { 
                if(d.r == "fail") {
                    //window.location.href = d.url;
                    alert(d.msg);
                    exit;
                } else {
                    //alert(d.msg);
                }
            }
        });
    }




/*
window.onerror = function(errorMsg) {
    $('#console').html($('#console').html()+'<br>'+errorMsg)
}*/

$.datetimepicker.setLocale('en');

$('#datetimepicker_format').datetimepicker({value:'2015/04/15 05:03', format: $("#datetimepicker_format_value").val()});
console.log($('#datetimepicker_format').datetimepicker('getValue'));


$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    datepicker:false,
    format:'H:i',
    step:60
});
$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({

    lang:'ch',
    timepicker:false,
    format:'d/m/Y',
    formatDate:'Y/m/d',
    minDate:'-1970/01/01', // yesterday is minimum date
    maxDate:'+1970/01/07' // and tommorow is maximum date calendar
});


</script>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. 2. **You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)** and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: Your way of using the database with php ist quiet insecure as Magnus Eriksson mentioned. You should get familiar with the current way. You can find an example at W3School: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp